# If condition controlled with a loop variable

Tags: conditionals, counters, loops

I want to print some images according to a variable being changed in a loop: if variable `group` is 1, then the image should not be printed. But if the value of `group` is 2, then the image should be printed. So I am looking for sort of an "if" condition.

I have already looked at the if conditions in LaTeX but I am not finding a solution that fits my case (controlling the if with a variable which is changing in a loop).

```
\newcounter{group}
\newcounter{subj}
\newcounter{number_of_runs_simona}
\forloop{group}{1}{\value{group} < 2}{
    \forloop{subj}{1}{\value{subj} < 2}{
    \forloop{number_of_runs_simona}{1}{\value{number_of_runs} < 26}{
    \centering

    \textbf{\large Group \arabic{group}, Subject \arabic{subj}, Run \arabic{number_of_runs}}

    \begin{figure}[!ht]
      \centering
        \includegraphics{\FILENAMEONE{\arabic{group}}{\arabic{subj}}{\arabic{number_of_runs_simona}}}
    \end{figure}

    \clearpage
    }
    }
    }
```

Figure "FILENAMEONE" should only be printed when the variable `group` has value 2.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcount\group
\newcount\subj
\newcount\nors

\group=0
\loop
  \advance\group by 1
  \subj=0
  {\loop
     \advance\subj by 1
     \nors=0
     {\loop
       \advance\nors by 1
        {
          group \the\group, subject \the\subj, run \the\nors
          \par
          \ifnum\group=2
            \begin{figure}[h!]
              \centering
              \emph{includegraphics filenameone-\the\group-\the\subj-\the\nors}
              \caption{Test of filenameone-\the\group-\the\subj-\the\nors}
            \end{figure}
            \par
          \fi
        }
        \ifnum\nors<26
      \repeat}
     \ifnum\subj<2  
   \repeat}
  \ifnum\group<2
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Sorry, I have always used a mixture of low-level `\if` commands and counter definitions, even if it is probably a bad practice.

I am not sure how `\ifnum\value{group}=2` would work in your case but maybe that is all you need to wrap around your `figure` environment to get your original example working ...

Comment: Indeed, adding \ifnum\value{group}=2 solved my problem. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind an additional package, `pgffor` is quite handy to provide foreach-loops.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

test

\foreach \n in {1,...,2}{
    \ifnum\n=2%
        \includegraphics{pic}%
    \fi%
}

\end{document}
```