# If clause within a loop

Tags: foreach, loops

I have a similar issue as the one discussed here [If condition controlled with a loop variable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310297/if-condition-controlled-with-a-loop-variable).

To summarize my case: when looping through a continous range of numbers, from 1 to 24, I'd like do something special if the number is on this list: 9, 10, 12, 14, ..., 18.

My first try was to nest an `\ifnum\value{\x} in {9,10,12,14,...,18}` clause into a `\foreach \x in {1,...,24}`... but I suddenly found worrisome not to know that `\ifnum\value{\x}` can be followed only by `=`, `>`, or `<`.

Now, if I set `\ifnum\value{\x} = {9,10,12,14,...,18}` as in the example below, I get only (and weird) outcomes when `\x = {9,10,12,14,...,18}`.

Every comment is welcome!

Example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,24}
    {
      \subsection{Question \x}
       \begin{figure}[h]
           \centering
           \ifnum\value{\x} = {9,10,12,14,...,18} {
               \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/univariate/q\x_a.pdf}
               \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/univariate/q\x_b.pdf}
           }
           \else {
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/univariate/q\x.pdf}
           }
           \fi
           \vspace{-1cm}
          \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
           \caption{}
        \end{figure}
        \clearpage
    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not a compilable document...

Comment: there is no loop defined here you just get an undefined command error on `\foreach`

Comment: Thanks David. I'm fixing the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some code I have written can be of help:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % smaller pictures

\ExplSyntaxOn

%%% code for cycles (communication to GuiTmeeting 2016)
\NewDocumentCommand{\newforeach}{ m +m }
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__newforeach_type_tl
  \keys_set:nn { newforeach }
   {
    start = 1, step = 1, end = 0, list=, #1
   }
  \__newforeach_exec:n { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__newforeach_type_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { V }

\keys_define:nn { newforeach }
 {
  type .choice:,
  type .value_required:n = true,
  type/integers .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__newforeach_type_tl { integers },
  type/fp       .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__newforeach_type_tl { fp },
  type/alph     .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__newforeach_type_tl { alph },
  type/Alph     .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__newforeach_type_tl { Alph },
  list     .clist_set:N = \l_newforeach_list_clist,
  list*    .code:n = \clist_set:NV \l_newforeach_list_clist #1,

  start .tl_set:N = \l_newforeach_start_tl,
  step  .tl_set:N = \l_newforeach_step_tl,
  end   .tl_set:N = \l_newforeach_end_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__newforeach_exec:n
 {
  \str_case:VnF \l__newforeach_type_tl
   {
    {integers}{\__newforeach_exec_integers:n { #1 }}
    {fp}      {\__newforeach_exec_fp:n       { #1 }}
    {alph}    {\__newforeach_exec_alph:n     { #1 }}
    {Alph}    {\__newforeach_exec_Alph:n     { #1 }}
   }
   {\__newforeach_exec_list:n { #1 }}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__newforeach_exec_integers:n
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn
   { \l_newforeach_start_tl }
   { \l_newforeach_step_tl }
   { \l_newforeach_end_tl }
   { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__newforeach_exec_fp:n
 {
  \fp_step_inline:nnnn
   { \l_newforeach_start_tl }
   { \l_newforeach_step_tl }
   { \l_newforeach_end_tl }
   { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__newforeach_exec_list:n
 {
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_newforeach_list_clist { #1 }
 }

%%% code for exceptions
\NewDocumentCommand{\ifinclistTF}{mmmm}
 {
  \clist_if_in:nnTF { #2 } { #1 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newforeach{type=integers,end=24}{%
  \subsection{Question #1}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \ifinclistTF{#1}{9,10,12,14,16,18}
    {
     %\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/univariate/q\x.pdf}
     {\Huge q#1}%
    }
    {%
     %\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/univariate/q\x_a.pdf}
     %\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/univariate/q\x_b.pdf}
     {\Huge q#1\_a} {\Huge q#1\_b}%
    }
  \end{minipage}
  \clearpage
}

\end{document}
```

The main difference is you don't use `\x` in the loop body, but `#1`. The `\newforeach` loops can be of different types, here `integers` is used. The starting point and the step are, by default, 1, so it's only needed to set the end point.

For the exceptions, I defined a further user level command.

In the code I changed the `\includegraphics` declarations to just the names, since I don't have your pictures. Just uncomment the `\includegraphics` lines and remove the ones with `\Huge`.

The following pictures shows the pages from 7 to 12, where the exceptions for 9, 10 and 12 show up.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @egreg!  Useful and instructive example!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgffor,graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,24}
    {
      \subsection{Question \x}
       \begin{figure}[h]
           \centering
           \xdef\IsInside{0}
           \foreach \y in {9,10,12,14,...,18}
           {\ifnum\y=\x
           \xdef\IsInside{1}
           \fi}
           \ifnum\IsInside=1
                \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}~
                \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b.pdf}
            \else 
             \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck.pdf}
           \fi
           \caption{}

        \end{figure}
        \clearpage
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @marmot!  I've just seen your reply. I will try to implemet it.

Comment: Thank you @marmot!  It worked very well!